# Localstack s3 ls astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localstack

I am using the latest localstack with docker. I am trying to ls s3:

```
$ aws s3 --endpoint='http://localhost:4572' ls
```

And I am getting the following result:

```
astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

**What's wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Use aws2, the one compatible with latest python.  That resolved this issue for me.

for linux :

```
curl "https://d1vvhvl2y92vvt.cloudfront.net/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

for macos:

```
curl "https://d1vvhvl2y92vvt.cloudfront.net/awscli-exe-macos.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Comment: Adding a +1 but interested in solving this for v1